# Is Hibernate @Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN) correct when it's applied to @ManyToOne?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, all-delete-orphan

Let's imagine the scenario: Entity `Company` and Entity `Address` has **one-to-many bidirectional** relationship. So Entity `Address` will look like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class AddressHbm{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "id-generator")
    @Column(name="address_id")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} )
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    @JoinColumn(name="company_id")
    private Company company = null;

    @Column(name="address_name")
    private String name;

    // other properties and methods
}
```

I'm going to migrate these codes to `Hibernate 4.3` where `CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN` is deprecated. When I am trying to replace `CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN` with `orphanRemoval = true`, it seems that `orphanRemoval = true` doesn't even exist in `@ManyToOne`.

So my question is:

- Does `AddressHbm` use `@Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)` in `@ManayToOne` incorrectly?
- If `@Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)` is misused here, is it valid to just remove it?

Comment: I am using Hibernate 5.3.6.Final. DELETE_ORPHAN didn't work for me in a @ManyToOne relation. The orphan element is not deleted. I also tried it in a manyToMany relation. It deleted the referenced row even if it is not orphan (wow hibernate). I don't know in version 4.3 but in 5.3.6 it is useless with a manyToOne relation so it can be removed. The problem is that i'm not aware of an equivalent for a manyToX relations. So if you need to delete the orphans, you need to do it manually.